# How can I constrain a generic argument to one which extends a class/constructor implementing a specific interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

A function I need to design accepts a class/constructor type defined as a generic argument type. However, I need to constrain that generic type to a class/constructor which implements a specific interface.

I was able to accomplish this goal by defining the interface, defining an abstract stub class which implements that interface, then using the `typeof` operator to reference the abstract stub class.

Here's a code sample demonstrating the error and workaround.

```js
interface Interface {
    get FooVal(): any;
}
abstract class StubClass implements Interface {
    abstract get FooVal(): any;
}
function Foo<T extends typeof StubClass>( bar: T ) { }
function Bar<T extends        Interface>( bar: T ) { }

class UserClass implements Interface {
    get FooVal() { return null; }
}
Foo( UserClass ); // No Errors/Warnings
Bar( UserClass ); // Argument of type 'typeof UserClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interface'.
```

Is there any way to avoid having to define the abstract stub class?

Comment: `typeof StubClass` is related to `new () => StubClass` which extends `new () => Interface`. It's a little odd that `Stublcass` and `typeof Stubclass` are both types but they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a constructable type.

```
interface Interface { get FooVal(): any; }
type InterfaceContructor = { new(): Interface }
```

Here `InterfaceConstructor` is a type that returns an object of type `Interface` when instantiated.

Now you can do:

```
function bar<T extends InterfaceContructor>( bar: T ) { }

class UserClass implements Interface {
    get FooVal() { return null; }
}

bar( UserClass ); // okay
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&moduleResolution=99&module=1&jsx=0&isolatedModules=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJyDeyDmEYyAYgPZkBqcANgBQCUAXMnCAJ4DcyAvgFBh2ABxTpIsRBADCZcFACuCMGSjIAvLmQgIAd0YsxmSbz584AIwDOYKImIIacS5eQBlMPPNTHz5MAC2QjQQ-hDgLoYS2Dh8yHGsVjZ2BESkFNT0zKwcnHz8MPIgSsCyyDAUADwAKsgQAB6QIAAmLoIiZDBuHl4+lgB8dMjmcFAsNQya+YXFpcNQ1bUNYS1oGFHSsjaKylADQyNjyBN4-HwOTi4AqpbQ3hd+gcGh4aviWCgx8SnE5FS0jJooER5FAQFp5DQaNx+PkKINrrdekduAB6FFlUAQPhzeE3KB3XwMVHomCYoA)

Comment: Is there any way to describe that constructable type as one which contains a private or protected constructor? To make matters more complicated, I'd like to use this on a type which has to be created via a factory method, and as such has a protected constructor.

Interestingly, the stub class method will allow this, but I don't think I'm really understanding why

Comment: That's bit out of scope for this question. Feel free to post a new question with proper example and I bet you'll get some help there.